# VHosts config location

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I removed Plesk from my server and now I'm  trying to figure out how the virtual hosting works.

My etc/apache2/apache2.conf and etc/apache2/sites-available/default both appear to point to /var/www/ yet when I open www.domain.com in a browser it is being pointed at /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/

Is there some entry in some configuration file I don't know about?

How can I change the location of my httpdocs?

Comment: What version of apache are you using could it be the mpm-itk? It automatically serves files from a path parsed from the hostname.

Comment: I meant mod_vhost_alias see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Comment: apache2 version is  2.2.22. I Don't think that's the issue, It looked promising but I don't have a /user/local/apache2/ folder

Comment: Is the VirtualDocumentRoot set anywhere in /etc/apache2/ e.g cd /etc/apache2; grep -lir VirtualDocumentRoot ./*

Comment: grep -r DocumentRoot *
sites-available/default:        DocumentRoot /var/www
sites-available/default-ssl:    DocumentRoot /var/www
sites-enabled/000-default:      DocumentRoot /var/www

Comment: grep -lir VirtualDocumentRoot ./* turned up no results

Comment: the only refeence i can find to domain.com = DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs" in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf

Comment: You should write your solution as an answer, so someone can upvote it.  It's alright to answer your own questions, and you get reputation for it.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

This file: /etc/apache2/conf.d/zz010_psa_https.conf contained:

```
# ATTENTION!
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE OR ANY PART OF IT. THIS CAN RESULT IN IMPROPER PLESK
# FUNCTIONING OR FAILURE, CAUSE DAMAGE AND LOSS OF DATA.

Include '/opt/psa/admin/conf/generated/13734840460.49232200_server.include'
```

The included file was basically a second apache2.conf, overriding all the settings of the original.